# Attending a baptism: Haram or shirk?

Tags: halal-haram, shirk, baptism

I've read that it is haram to attend non-Muslim rituals like the Hindu [diwali](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diwali) and Christian [baptisms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baptism). That sounds pretty logical to me. However, some scholars say that it is shirk. They say that it is worse than murder. But if I'm attending these rituals without actually accepting their faith, then how can they be shirk?

I'm doing it for fun. I can attend a non-Muslim ritual once and then ask Allah for forgiveness and never attend such rituals again. But if it actually is shirk, then there is no point in asking Allah for forgiveness, despite the fact that I'm only doing it for fun and not to accept their religion.

Comment: Haram or Shirk, you left no space for halal/allowed/encouraged/discouraged?